# calculating euclidean distance from mol2 file

Tags: regex, perl

This is my program and i want to calculate euclidean distance between two atoms at different times.So i could i modify this program to make it possible.My input is

```
  1 I          -6.2528   -0.8879    0.3208 I       1  LIG1       -0.0425
  2 O          -0.1927    0.3708   -0.4256 O.3     1  LIG1       -0.4750
  3 N           2.7475    3.2931    0.6111 N.3     1  LIG1       -0.2164
  4 C           0.6554    0.0834    0.6881 C.3     1  LIG1        0.1896
  5 C           1.3107    1.3881    1.1695 C.3     1  LIG1        0.0670
  6 C           1.6435   -0.9764    0.2598 C.ar    1  LIG1        0.0172
  7 C           2.1448    2.0726    0.0863 C.3     1  LIG1        0.0928
  8 C          -1.5245    0.1089   -0.2623 C.ar    1  LIG1        0.1349
  9 C           2.1274   -1.8960    1.1905 C.ar    1  LIG1       -0.0008
 10 C           2.0723   -1.0350   -1.0663 C.ar    1  LIG1       -0.0008
 11 C          -2.4708    1.1273   -0.3768 C.ar    1  LIG1        0.0125
 12 C           3.0398   -2.8742    0.7949 C.ar    1  LIG1       -0.0002
 13 C           2.9846   -2.0133   -1.4618 C.ar    1  LIG1       -0.0002
 14 C          -1.9331   -1.1945    0.0206 C.ar    1  LIG1        0.0370
 15 C           3.4684   -2.9327   -0.5314 C.ar    1  LIG1       -0.0000
 16 C           3.5783    3.9360   -0.3969 C.3     1  LIG1        0.1075
```

here is my program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $num = 0;

my @arrayx;
my @arrayy;
my @arrayz;

while (<>) {
    # remove new line char
    chomp;

    # Find x, y, z coordinates and store in separate arrays
    if (/^ATOM/) {
        my @line = $_ =~ m/^(.....).(.....).(....).(...)..(....)....(........)(........)               (........)/;

        my $x = $line[5];
        $arrayx[$num] = $x;

        my $y = $line[6];
        $arrayy[$num] = $y;

        my $z = $line[7];
        $arrayz[$num] = $z;

        ++$num;
    }
}

# Calculate distance between all atom coordinates
for my $i ( 0 .. $num ) {
    for my $j ( $i + 1 .. $num ) {

        # skip if j array element does not exist
        unless ( defined( $arrayx[$j] )
            && defined( $arrayy[$j] )
            && defined( $arrayz[$j] ) )
        {
            print "Skipping i:$i j:$j\n";
            sleep(1);
            next;
        }

        my $dist =
          sqrt( ( $arrayx[$i] - $arrayx[$j] )**2 +
              ( $arrayy[$i] - $arrayy[$j] )**2 +
              ( $arrayz[$i] - $arrayz[$j] )**2 );
        print "$dist\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Does the code you've shown not work? What is the problem? Does it produce an error?  What have you tried?

Comment: what is your problem? please specify before your question gets flagged

Comment: i want to calculate Euclidean distance between two atoms and thus iterate to next atom in same manner.My input is Mol2 file format.So i have problem with regular expression usage.I have written this code which takes input a mol2 file then reads the line but there is error in regular expressions usage.This program not working what i expected.

Comment: This is not your complete input file based on the match against `/^ATOM/` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You post some sample data, but you don't actually tell us what it means.  I suspect that the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th columns refer to x, y, and z respectively, but you should confirm this.

If that's the case, then the following is a cleaned up version of your code.  Perhaps it will help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @data;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    # Find x, y, z coordinates and store in separate arrays
    my @line = split;

    push @data, {
        x => $line[2],
        y => $line[3],
        z => $line[4],
        name => $line[5],
    };
}

# Calculate distance between all atom coordinates
for my $i ( 0 .. $#data ) {
    for my $j ( $i + 1 .. $#data ) {

        my $dist =
          sqrt( ( $data[$i]{x} - $data[$j]{x} )**2 +
              ( $data[$i]{y} - $data[$j]{y} )**2 +
              ( $data[$i]{z} - $data[$j]{z} )**2 );

        printf "%-6s %-6s %f\n", $data[$i]{name}, $data[$j]{name}, $dist;
    }
}

__DATA__
  1 I          -6.2528   -0.8879    0.3208 I       1  LIG1       -0.0425
  2 O          -0.1927    0.3708   -0.4256 O.3     1  LIG1       -0.4750
  3 N           2.7475    3.2931    0.6111 N.3     1  LIG1       -0.2164
  4 C           0.6554    0.0834    0.6881 C.3     1  LIG1        0.1896
  5 C           1.3107    1.3881    1.1695 C.3     1  LIG1        0.0670
  6 C           1.6435   -0.9764    0.2598 C.ar    1  LIG1        0.0172
  7 C           2.1448    2.0726    0.0863 C.3     1  LIG1        0.0928
  8 C          -1.5245    0.1089   -0.2623 C.ar    1  LIG1        0.1349
  9 C           2.1274   -1.8960    1.1905 C.ar    1  LIG1       -0.0008
 10 C           2.0723   -1.0350   -1.0663 C.ar    1  LIG1       -0.0008
 11 C          -2.4708    1.1273   -0.3768 C.ar    1  LIG1        0.0125
 12 C           3.0398   -2.8742    0.7949 C.ar    1  LIG1       -0.0002
 13 C           2.9846   -2.0133   -1.4618 C.ar    1  LIG1       -0.0002
 14 C          -1.9331   -1.1945    0.0206 C.ar    1  LIG1        0.0370
 15 C           3.4684   -2.9327   -0.5314 C.ar    1  LIG1       -0.0000
 16 C           3.5783    3.9360   -0.3969 C.3     1  LIG1        0.1075
```

Outputs:

```
I        O.3      6.234280
I        N.3      9.928264
I        C.3      6.985811
I        C.3      7.943991
I        C.ar     7.897032
I        C.3      8.907258
I        C.ar     4.867282
I        C.ar     8.485305
I        C.ar     8.441148
I        C.ar     4.341797
I        C.ar     9.514335
I        C.ar     9.474901
I        C.ar     4.340960
I        C.ar     9.970415
I        C.3      10.974317
O.3      N.3      4.273097
O.3      C.3      1.429056
O.3      C.3      2.416496
O.3      C.ar     2.378309
....
```

Comment: What you did is exactly right,Thanks Miller for your great support, it helps me a lot. Would you  also help me to get the output with the atom name within which you have calculated distance so i can better understand the output.

Comment: I made an update for you that outputs what I assume is the name.  You might've figured this out by now, but if not, this should help.  Btw, if this is the correct answer, feel free to mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You are very unclear about what is the problem. It is not clear what does happen and what should happen. Especially what should happen. I do not know a mol2 format and even less do i know how to compute euclidean distances at different times from one.

But: Your comment implies that the problem is with the line

```
my @line = $_ =~ m/^(.....).(.....).(....).(...)..(....)....(........ (........)               (........)/;
```

I am not entirely sure what you try to do here. Do you try to get the fields of a line of your pasted text file (mol2?) into the array `@line`? If so, try

```
my @line = split ' ', $_;
```

instead. That will remove any leading whitespaces and then split the string at any number of whitespaces. So if you split the first of your example lines this way, you will end with `$line[2]` == -6.2528, `$line[3]` == -0.8879, `$line[4]` == 0.3208
Assuming those are the numbers you are after.

Comment: The thing that you call numbers are x,y,z coordinates of file and i want to calculate distance between one atom(I) to other atom (C) at position 7.So my question is How could i read the input format so i can calculate distance by using numbers of two atoms(distance between two atoms).

Comment: Did you try the suggestion i made? That should give you an array where the coordinates are in position 2, 3 and 4, waiting for you to be used however you like.